# Appending an elements contents with the contents from another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a feed of posts each with an image and description.

Example code:

```
 <div class="post">

    <img id="thumb" src="#">

    <div class="description">
        <p> description here </p>
        <p> other info </p>
        <p> date of post </p>
    </div>

 </div>
```

I have a popup also, where when you click on the image thumbnail the image is enlarged by using this jQuery:

```
$("#thumb").click( function() {

    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#popup .image img").attr('src', source);

});
```

This is the HTML for the popup:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
        <p>  </p>
    </div>              
</div>
```

How would I be able to display the description elements inside the popup description bar corresponding to the post clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your function :

```
   $("#thumb").click( function() {
    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#popup .image img").attr('src', source);
    var description = $(this).siblings(".description").html();
    $("#popup .desc").html(description);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your function:

```
$("#thumb").click( function() {
    var source = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#popup .image img").attr('src', source);
    $("#popup .desc p").html($(this).next().html());
});
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't go with next() assuming that more details can be added to the post or the html can be refactored in the future.